# Can I run JSP code inside a PHP file or vice versa?

Tags: php, jsp

For example in my `view.jsp`:

```
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/images/helloWorld.jpg" />
<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>
```

or for example I want to get the *ContextPath* inside a PHP file (`index.php`). How can I accomplish that?

Comment: More important question: Why do you want to do that mess? What kind of webserver are you using to have php+jsp?

Comment: Why not stick to one of them? The only kind of thing I know regarding this is `PHP Java Bridge`

Comment: I'm sure it's possible (although I've only [seen it done with Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::View::PHP)). Given the way JSP works, I suspect going JSP->PHP->client will be easier than PHP->JSP->client.

Comment: Btw if you want `ContextPath` there are also PHP functions returning the same..

Comment: @AlfaTeK I am using Liferay/Tomcat that supports PHP and JSP. I have a portlet developed with PHP and other porlets in JSP.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this information via PHP without calling out to JSP. To get the location of the current request, use

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

This will return the complete URI, including the script name. If you want only the directory structure and not the trailing script name, you can use `trim()` to remove the excess. For convenience, note that the script name is stored here:

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
```

For additional information and examples, see https://coderwall.com/p/gdam2w